# Bulk insert Datetime Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I am trying to use `BULK INSERT` in SQL Server 2012 to import data from a text file into database table. I am using a UTC datetime value with the `Z` designator (DOB field) in text file. But while executing `BULK INSERT`, I am getting a "data conversion error".

Can anyone please help me?

**Script**

```
CREATE TABLE Info
(
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
DOB DATETIME
)

BULK INSERT Info FROM 'F:\InfoTextFile.txt'  WITH (FORMATFILE='F:\InfoFormatFile.fmt')
```

**Contents of F:\InfoTextFile.txt**

> John      Smith     1988-08-23T00:00:00.0Z
>
> William   Alexander 1987-07-22T00:00:00.0Z

**Content of 'F:\InfoFormatFile.fmt'**

```
11.0

3

1     SQLCHAR     0     10     ""     1     FirstName     ""

2     SQLCHAR     0     10     ""     2     LastName      ""

3     SQLDATETIME 0 22     "\r\n" 3     DOB           ""
```

**Error:**

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 1, column 3 (DOB).
>
> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load: An unexpected end of
>   file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for
>   linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give
>   any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
--C:\InfoTextFile.txt ->
--John Smith 1988-08-23T00:00:00.0Z
--William Alexander 1987-07-22T00:00:00.0Z

--C:\InfoFormatFile.fmt ->
--11.0
--3
--1     SQLCHAR     0     10     " "     1     FirstName     ""
--2     SQLCHAR     0     10     " "     2     LastName      ""
--3     SQLCHAR     0     22     "\n"    3     DOB           ""

BULK INSERT Info 
FROM 'C:\InfoTextFile.txt' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FORMATFILE='C:\InfoFormatFile.fmt')
```